# Changing a style parameter dynamically with Java in GWT

Tags: java, javascript, css, gwt, dynamic-css

By any chance is there a way to change/alter a style parameter with Java that is used with GWT. 
Suppose if i have a component in ui.xml file as ui:field="DivUserNameTop" 
and if i want to alter the color of the DIV 'DivUserNameTop' what property can i use? I tried some googling but nothing helped.

TO MAKE IT MORE CLEAR - If suppose i have to load the color of the div from the session(i.e each user has each color pre-defined in a db and that value will be set in the session say SESSION_COLOR once they authenticate), how do i set the SESSION_COLOR to a DIV with GWT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use css styles.  You can either use styles directly from a css file, or get a little more efficient and wrap the styles in a cssresource class.  Then to set the styles on gwt widgets you call methods on the widget.  To set styles on a DOM element you can call setElementProperty or DOM.setStyleAttribute to set individual styles properties.

Comment: Deanna, If suppose i have to load the color of the div from the session(i.e each user has each color pre-defined in a db and that value will be set in the session say SESSION_COLOR), how do i set the SESSION_COLOR to a DIV with GWT.

Comment: I guess first question, is the div part of a gwt widget or is it defined just in the DOM?

Comment: The reason I asked the question is that the methods are different if it is a widget or just a html div.  If your question is really about how to get the information from your session variable to the client then that also raises lots of questions and doesn't have just 1 answer.  I would assume that when you authenticate the user you send back some user info in some manner (either inside a jsp page or a request response).  Put the color in that response, then use the widget or div methods to set that color on the client.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. I will get a response color after user authentication and i need to apply the color for the div. How could this be possible. Sorry if it sounds silly. I m a newbie to GWT and Java!

Comment: To get the div element, you have an id set in the div  <div id="divIdName")  then in your code you get it with DOM.getElementById("divIdName") .   At this point if the colors are defined in a css style you can setClassName("stylename"),  or if the colors are just colors callsetAttribute("background-color", yourcolor).